# List of numbers in C# and getting min and max value without retaining variables stored in previous loop

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, numbers

So I have this thing that displays minimum and maximum numbers from a series of numbers inputed, please note I am just a beginner and haven't learned arrays or sorting yet:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double number, maxValue= Double.MinValue , minValue= Double.MaxValue;
            string goOn = "Y";

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a series of numbers, when you wish to stop entering numbers please enter -99.");
            Console.WriteLine("The smallest and largest values will then be displayed.");
            Console.WriteLine("Remember not to enter -99 unless you want the series to end.");
            do
            {
                while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter whole numbers only");

                while (number != -99)
                {
                    process(ref minValue, ref maxValue, number);

                    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter whole numbers only");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("The smallest value is {0} and the largest value is {1}.", minValue, maxValue);
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to enter another series of numbers?");
                Console.WriteLine("If so enter y, if you want to end press any other key");
                goOn = Console.ReadLine();
                if (goOn.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your set of numbers.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Remember not to enter -99 unless you want the series to end.");
                }

            } while (goOn.ToUpper() == "Y");
        }
        static void process(ref double minValue, ref double maxValue, double number)
        {
            if (number > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = number;
            }
            if (number < minValue)
            {
                minValue = number;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But when I enter a series of numbers, and then stop, and then make another list of numbers, it retains the minimum and maximum from the previous list as shown:

[image: Console example showing numbers 6, 7, -7, 3, 5, 100, 44. -7 is the minimum value and 100 is the maximum. Then another list is made, 5, 55, 34, but -7 is still the minimum and 100 is still the maximum]

Also I am sorta doing my own version of someone else's program like this but can't figure out how he is able to do it with setting maxValue = 0 and minValue = 0.  He does use Int64 instead of double though and used three modules instead of 1 and another if statement for if minValue and maxValue are 0.

Comment: It's worth noting that because you're using `double`, you *can* support decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to search for min and max in new sequence, just clear out the previously saved values:

```
if (goOn.ToUpper() == "Y")
{
    maxValue= Double.MinValue;
    minValue= Double.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your set of numbers.");
    Console.WriteLine("Remember not to enter -99 unless you want the series to end.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never resetting the values of `maxValue` and `minValue` at the end of each iteration of the do-while loop. Since you're not doing that your program is holding onto the previous numbers that were used.

You should reset them both to whatever you set them to at the beginning of your program at the last line before the end of the do-while loop.

Comment: Actually needs to set `maxValue` to `Double.MinValue` and `minValue` to `Double.MaxValue`